# Events not firing with Marionette

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, ecmascript-6

I'm creating a simple page using a *CompositeView* from Marionette, with a parent lodash template that wraps a group of templates: one for each item in its *Collection*.

The page displays properly, and each *ItemView* renders properly with it's own child template, but binding a 'click' event fails to register anywhere in the application, even if moved into the *CompositeView*.

I have my suspicions that this is happening due to the events being bound before the element is created, and it not updating afterwards. From what I have read, it uses / used .live() / .on(), but I can't see any other reason that it wouldn't register.

Is there a way to make sure that events are rebound with `onRender()`? Am I doing something else wrong entirely?

Environment: RequireJS, BabelJS (es6), Backbone 1.1.2, Marionette 2.4.1, jQuery 1.10.2

I've created [a gist of the code in question.](https://gist.github.com/NoiSek/0ed41a4e60209b97e452)

Comment: Please trim down the code to a small demonstration and put it in the question. As long as you indent it 4 spaces, SO will do syntax highlighting. Linking to code elsewhere makes it much less likely people are going to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Non ES6:** Try assigning `this.events` before the parent constructor call, in Backbone 1.2.1+ the events are created BEFORE `initialize` in the parent constructor. In 1.1.2 they are created AFTER `initialize`, but still as the last thing the parent constructor does - so you should either assign them in `initialize`, or do it before the super call (I recommend before super call in the constructor so that if you upgrade it doesn't break again).

In **ES6** you can't use `this` before the super call.

You could call `this.delegateEvents();` again, but it's not ideal as it stops listening and then re-listening to any existing events which is less efficient (though the impact is probably negligible).

You can use es7's `static` property on the class definition if you are using a transpiler that supports it (e.g. Babel), or make events a function which returns an object if you need it to be dynamic.

Comment: Umm, using `this` befor the `super()` call is a syntax error.